# Generating python dictionary only stores last value from iterable

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Here's a list of objects returned from database:

`>>> credit_transactions`

```
[<Transaction: some detail>, <Transaction: more detail>, <Transaction: hello>, <Transaction: yay dummy data>]
```

Following is the code I'm using to generate dictionary.
Here's what I want to do, if `tr.category` is available more than once, then `tr.amount` should get added to the last value.
What I'm getting right now is only the last value of `tr.category`.

```
credit = { tr.category:tr.amount for tr in credit_transactions}
```

For the following value of `credit_transactions`, the above mentioned code generated dictionary key,value pair for only the last value. I want sum of the values if key is repeated.

```
>>> for tr in credit_transactions:
...  tr.category
... 
<Category: Bonus>
<Category: Lottery>
<Category: Lottery>
<Category: Bonus>
<Category: Salary>
<Category: Bonus>
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sum explicitly:

```
sums = {}
for tr in credit_transactions:
    try:
        sums[tr.category] += tr.amount  # not first in this category
    except KeyError:
        sums[tr.category] = tr.amount  # first in this category
```

Or use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which automatically initializes missing keys to zero:

```
from collections import defaultdict
sums = defaultdict(float)
for tr in credit_transactions:
    sums[tr.category] += tr.amount
```

As you already noticed, if you use plain dict-comprehension, later items overwrite earlier ones, instead of summing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a dictionary comprehension with multiple values to one key. It will continually overwrite. You'll have to use a `defaultdict` (or `dict.setdefault`)

`defaultdict` makes all values lists by default. ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)):

```
from collections import defaultdict

credit = defaultdict(list)
for tr in credit_transactions:
    credit[tr.category].append(tr.amount)
```

`dict.setdefault` to set to empty list if empty. ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault))

```
credit = {}
for tr in credit_transactions:
    credit.setdefault(tr.category, []).append(tr.amount)
```